# Fetch an API -> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript

i have a problem for fetch a data of an api.. This api -> https://resmush.it/api

**My request work on Postman** but not on my website i have this error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

My code :

```js
const params = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};

fetch('http://api.resmush.it/ws.php?img=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png&qlty=50', params)
    .then(reponseBis => reponseBis.json())
    .then(dataBis => console.log(dataBis));
```

Thank for help !

Comment: I see your problem ... you think you can bypass CORS on the client side ... that would make CORS pointless

Comment: also, `mode: 'no-cors'` will guarantee no returned data ... fortunately that API does allow CORS ... just stop serring meaningless headers - i.e get rid of `mode: ...` and  ALL your headers which are not required for this request

Comment: in fact, you don't need params at all, since the default method is GET anyway ... also, it's `.then` not `then`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** It seems this header `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` is causing troubles. The code should work if you remove it

This meta tag will upgrade `HTTP` to `HTTPS`, however the API you're using doesn't serve `HTTPS`

[From the docs:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests)

> Note that, if the requested resource is not actually available via HTTPS, the request will fail without any fallback to HTTP.

**-------**

> `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mywebsite.com/page.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://api.resmush.it/ws.php?img=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png&qlty=50'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

The issue is that this link `https://upload.wikimedia.org` is `HTTPS`, while `http://api.resmush.it` is `HTTP`. Change the resmush url to `https://` or change the wikimedia link to `http://`

**---------**

Have a look at [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Using no-cors can only be used to POST data to an API not allowing cors. But doing so will return an empty response. The API you gave allows cors, so this is not needed at all.

The `Content-Type` header should be `Accept`

```js
const params = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

fetch('http://api.resmush.it/ws.php?img=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png&qlty=50', params)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(e => console.error(e));
```

```
{
  "src": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png",
  "dest": "http://par3.static.resmush.it/a95239e7e37bade3af9ca3b7eabb8f11/1200px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png",
  "src_size": 48597,
  "dest_size": 19545,
  "percent": 60,
  "output": "json",
  "expires": "Thu, 06 Aug 2020 09:52:12 +0200",
  "generator": "reSmush.it rev.2.0.6.20200328"
}
```

Comment: The same but with the line of the catch indicated

Comment: This code works perfectly fine for me, can you share your other code? It may be interfering

Comment: Yes in my code the MY_KEY is ok i eddited it for the forum ^^'

Comment: Ah ok, can you log this data you get from the first fetch and show me what it looks like?